# Acquired an old bike with a house purchase; does it have value worthy of restoration?

Tags: vintage, restoration

Just wondering if someone could help me out. I bought a house about 5 years ago and this bike was a feature in the garden. I've tried to research about it but nothing comes up for "copper city". Just really wanted to know if its worth anything and should be restored or is best left as is in the garden.

[image: Overall picture of a very rusty-looking bike with fenders and drop handlebars turned upside down]
[image: close-up showing the down tube and front fender]
[image: close-up showing the front of the head tube and fork crown]
[image: extreme close-up of a piece of metal beneath the rear of the left chain stay which is stamped "PERRY" and "England"]
[image: rear-view close-up of the saddle, labeled "Brooks"]
[image: extreme close-up of the drive-side crank which is stamped "Brampton Made in England"]
[image: rear view of the bike showing the rear fender with reflector]
[image: close-up of the fork]

Comment: Great work with the photos!

Comment: It's something of a classic.  Might be in the "English racer" category.  Probably dates from 1960 or earlier.  In very poor condition, though.

Comment: Per the answers below, probably not worth restoring. Depending on the aesthetics of your garden, could be an interesting decorative item. Mount it to a wooden fence or side of garage and let it continue rusting. Or lean it against a hedge/ vine-covered wall/fence and let it slowly disappear into the foliage, which could be cut back periodically to keep it visible enough to be intriguing.

Answer (score 6):

I can tell you a little about the saddle and the coaster brake.

It's a Brooks Hammock Saddle.
[I found a collection of Brooks Saddle catalogs](http://pedaling.org/brooks-brand.html). The oldest catalog with that saddle [type was 1912](http://pedaling.org/brooks-catalogues/brooks_1912_cy.pdf).
[image]

The newest catalog with that type of saddle [was 1959](http://pedaling.org/brooks-catalogues/brooks_1959_cs.pdf)
[image]
[image]

There is a gap in the catalog collection between 1959 and 2008. There was no hammock saddle in the 2008 catalog.

You have a Perry Coaster Brake.
Here is a [link to the history of the Perry and Co](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/Perry_and_Co).

There were different models and there are markings that can help identify the model. Knowing the model might help track down the year.
Here is a link to an article that [tells a little about the hub markings](https://rmalverson.blogspot.com/2012/01/perry-coaster-hub.html).

> My best guess on the model and manufacture date for this hub is that it is a B-10, made in 1955. The model "B" is stamped on the inside of the reaction arm, and 10-55 on the other. Some additional support for the 1955 date is the brake cylinder stamped "Perry 4-55." The later model 100 had "B-100" stamped on the outside of the arm, under the two stars. It also had a different brake cylinder design, using a spring running in a channel around two brake shoes as opposed to the v-split with internal spring used in the B-10.  All Perry hubs feature a "xx-yy" stamp on the shell which designates the number of holes and spoke gauge for that shell (in this case 36-13).

Comment: That is an awesome find - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would call that a 70's bike at newest, and it may date to much earlier.

The saddle and its structure look very strange and may be the key to dating it better.  The leather top has perished and rotted, but the sprung wire frame is not your common saddle rails.

The bike would be a lot of work to restore, but not impossible if you had time.  One observation is the cranks appear to be crooked relative to each other, so there may be failed/broken internals.

I see cracks in the mudguards, so there would be welding or brazing required to fix them.

As for value, steel is around 5c/kilogram.  A steel bike is worth around 50c-$1 in scrap value.

The minimum you need will be new tyres/tubes, saddle, front brake, chain, and lots of lubricants.  Don't expect to break even if you're doing this with the intention of reselling it.

And do turn the handlebars back around where they go - as pictured they're likely to core-sample the rider.

Comment: Honestly that’s one of the few cases which looks hopeless and beyond repair. So much rust, and definitely more than just cosmetic damage in several places. Many of the threads are probably rusted shut too.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I really don't know anything about bikes. I thought it might be worth something to someone but if it's only worth scrap it can go back in the garden.

Comment: There was a reason it was left behind...

Comment: re: cranks -- another possibility is that the cotter pins were installed incorrectly. I did that once!

Comment: @Jake it DOES have value! Not as a bicycle(never ever try to ride it!!); rather as a garden ornament. It is beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

The bike as you see it there isn't really valuable as it is but you should bear in mind that it would have been a quality item when new and is fitted with some expensive components from well respected manufacturers (Brooks, Brampton; both well regarded).

The corrosion does not look particularly terminal to me. You obviously live in a dry environment. If that had been in a garden in Wales, there would be a pile of red dust after 5 years, not to mention the extra 50 years of life. You may find that a light restoration, to get it functional, plus some leatherworking to re-create the saddle, would make a nice bike for short rides or to run errands. It will certainly be quite cool and eye catching. This type of bike, when it looks smart, is often wated by the sort of retro-industrial stylist putting the finishing touches into a cafe or similar and that's where the monetary value is, if you can realise it.